# javascript replacing strings

Tags: javascript, string

I have a small custom made thumbnail gallery. On click of a thumbnail I want to get the bigger version of the image. To do this I am getting the `img`'s `src`. With that I want to replace a certain section of the string for another string. For example the thumbnail's source may look like this:

```
/media/uploads/headshots/width_60_259850_10150280251835435_717615434_9570015_4084479_n.jpg
```

I need to replace `width_60_` with `width_104_`. Is this possible with Javascript?

Comment: @JAAulde, SO should replace Google for such.  Otherwise, vote it down, vote to close, provide an answer, a relevant comment... but snotty remarks are not needed.

Comment: @Sparky672 I voted it down and provided a comment about why...standard SO procedure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the [JS `replace()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var imgSrc = "/media/uploads/headshots/width_60_259850_10150280251835435_717615434_9570015_4084479_n.jpg"
var newSrc = imgSrc.replace("width_60_", "width_104_");
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/RedEM/).