# How to replace part of a string with another string?

Tags: javascript, indexof

Here's what I'm trying to do. Honestly, I'm not even sure where to start.

```
var text1 = 'ThE foX iS brown',

        text2 = 'the fox is brown the fox is brown THE FOX IS BROWN',

        index = text2.toLowerCase().indexOf(text1.toLowerCase()),

        output = 'do something with substring?';

    alert(index);
```

The "text2" should be changed to: ThE foX iS brown the fox is brown THE FOX IS BROWN

```
    var text1 = 'ThE foX iS brown the FOX is BrO',

        text2 = 'the fox is brown the fox is brown THE FOX IS BROWN',

        index = text2.toLowerCase().indexOf(text1.toLowerCase()),

        output = 'do something with substring?';

    alert(index);
```

And in this case "text2" should be changed to: ThE foX iS brown the FOX is BrOwn THE FOX IS BROWN

I thought that maybe I should first try to find the "first" occurrence of the string "text1" within "text2" but it doesn't seem to work? And I thought after that I could use `substring`? Or maybe there's even an easier way to do this? I'm not sure. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: According to downvotes, this seems like a dumb question. Sorry.

Comment: it's not dumb, it just doesn't show much effort on your part. you mentioned a few ideas you had - why not try some of them then come back when you have a more specific question?

Comment: You can't modify strings in place in Javascript. Functions like `toLowerCase()` return a new string.

Comment: Can the match for `text1` be somewhere other than the beginning of `text2`?

Comment: @Barmar No, should start from beginning. I tried `replace`, but that cut off the rest of the string? And in this code above, it does not return the index, it's only empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript replacing strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769808/javascript-replacing-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you are simply trying to replace the first part of the string with text1.

You can try this.

```
int text1Size = text1.length;
output = text1 + text2.substring(text1Size);
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Easier too, I like it. Thank you. btw, I had to change it to `text1.length`. :)

Comment: Plus I had to remove `-1`. :) Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to replace the first occurrence of the substring `text1` in `text2` with `text1`, ignoring the case.

You can build a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that, using the "i"gnore-case flag.

Assuming you don't know the contents of `text1`, you have to escape some special characters interpreted by regular expressions.
Once you have your regular expression you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Here is an example:

```
// Function to escape Regular Expressions special characters.
// From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

var text1 = 'ThE foX iS brown';
var text2 = 'the fox is brown the fox is brown THE FOX IS BROWN';

// Create the Regular Expression with the "i"gnore-case flag
var re = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(text1), "i");

var output = text2.replace(re, text1);
// output -> ThE foX iS brown the fox is brown THE FOX IS BROWN
```

And [here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFPYJ/).

Comment: Wow, this looks good too! Thank you very much. I upvoted your answer! Thank you for the effort and explanation!

Comment: This solution is more general and will work wherever `text1` appears, not only at the begin of the string.